# Error Node Sass does not yet supported your current environment: OS X Unsupported architecture (arm64)

Tags: sass, node-sass

I'm having problems using node sass on mac M1, what workaround could solve the problem?

Comment: Add more details about your problem.

Answer (score 2):

npm install node-sass should bring you to the latest version.

Issue went away for me after updating.